# The eternal dilemma: bar.foo() or foo(bar)?

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, functional-programming

I was using `foo(bar)` as it's adopted for functional programming.

```
console.log(
    join(
        map(function(row){ return row.join(" "); },
            tablify(
                map(function(text){return align(text},
                    view),
                20))),
    "\n");
```

Now, with dot operator:

```
view.map(function(text){return align(text)})
    .tablify(20)
    .map(function(row){return row.join(" ");})
    .join("\n")
    .log();
```

I guess everyone will agree this reads too much better, and the only cost is that you have to modify the native types prototype. So, which?

Comment: This will help you find the right thing... just go to http://jsperf.com/ and paste your code there and compare the speed...

Comment: Who says the OOP approach has to modify native prototypes? jQuery, for instance, doesn't modify native prototypes, but still gives you array-like objects with chainable methods. As for the functional approach, it requires (the way it's written now) a lot of functions to be in the current scope - perhaps even in the global scope. That seems more suspect to me.

Comment: @Flambino how else would you do it? If you had it all inside an object your whole code would gain a substantial noise (if you're using them too much, which you should).

Comment: @Dokkat Sorry, not sure which approach you're referring to there

Comment: @Flambino you suggested I shouldn't have so many globals, so what instead? myLib.map?

Comment: @Dokkat Ah, for the functional approach. Yes, I'd namespace stuff where I can to avoid global namespace conflicts. Like, e.g. underscore.js does by using `_` for its namespace, or how jQuery uses `$`.

Comment: @Flambino but then again, your source is pretty much calls to chose functions so you are adding a huge noise to it! What's wrong in opening it to global scope for your app?

Comment: @Dokkat Nothing, if you can control it. But in JS, that's sort of impossible. There's no telling what other libraries might define, what certain browsers might define, what users' own extensions and little helper scripts might define. Maybe someone missed a `var` keyword in function, and made an implicit global that overwrites your stuff - or vice-versa. Maybe a new browser version will overwrite something with new native functions. The global scope is already crowded; namespacing your stuff limits your exposure to those issues. Which is why it's considered best practice to do so.

Comment: @Flambino good points, but aren't all those problems solved by simply loading your lib last?

Comment: @Dokkat Not if you're in conflict with built-in, native functions/properties that are protected and can't be overwritten. Then your code just gets ignored. Also, if you use a library and overwrite something that it depends on, then that library breaks. If all the code's run sequentially it's OK, but if it's event-driven it's no longer sequential, so event handlers that worked fine when they were defined, might break when they're triggered if they rely on stuff you've since overwritten.

Comment: @mikrowelt Faster is not always better. (And in fact, usually isn't.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the first variant can look nice, too, if you change the way you format the code and you always use the function as the last argument:

```
log(map(tablify(map(view, function(text) {
  return align(text)
}), 20), function(row) {
  return row.join(" ")
}).join("\n"))
```

Edit: Or if you really like indent:

```
log(map(tablify(map(view,
                    function(text) { return align(text) }
                ),
                20
        ),
        function(row) { return row.join(" ") }
    ).join("\n")
)
```